# Goodreads API: get genre?

Tags: api, recommendation-engine

You would think this would be an elementary part of the Goodreads API since getting the genre associated with an author or book is a fairly common task.  But, as far as I can tell, none of the xml returned by any of the relevant methods gives genre info.  For example,  given the author name "Stephen King" none of the returned xml contains info on the genres associated with the author--in this case,"Mystery & Thrillers, Horror, Literature & Fiction."

The "search.book" method does contain a search[field] option  which can be 'title', 'author', or 'genre.'  But that's of no help here since I need to know the genres given an author, not the authors given a genre.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a Goodreads developer about this. His reply: "Sorry, but our API doesn't supply author genre information."

Comment: Did you finally find any other API that has a decent book genre data?

Comment: I ended writing something that gets genre information using two APIs: the goodreads API  which, given a title, will give u an isbn but no genre information. and the ISBNdb API, which will give you category (very similar to genre) information.